# Answering a question with a different approach altogether

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614922/reintroduce-information-from-old-entries-in-ms-sq) with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616047/57475) that doesn't answer the question in any direct manner. My answer is suggesting a different design altogether.

The normal approach is to solve the problem before you, which sometimes ignores greater issues. Just wondered what the etiquette is around doing things like this. I think it's OK, but wondered if I should have done anything differently.

Comment: When the OP has an X/Y problem, this is the right thing to do.

Comment: I think it's important to remember that your answer isn't just for the OP. Other people will see it, and some of them may prefer to look at the bigger picture whether or not the OP does.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah I thought about that, but the question has a pretty obscure title. I was thinking about editing it for something more useful but couldn't figure one out.

Comment: This is why we allow *multiple* answers to be posted—because these types of answers are valuable to others and worth having on the site, even though they might not be exactly what the OP is looking for. Please keep posting these!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see a systemic problem in the question which should be fixed, which would incidentally also fix the direct problem posed, then by all means go for it. Your hands aren't tied to answering only the direct question at hand, especially if doing so means bending over backwards where a much more elegant solution could be achieved by altering the starting conditions.

Whether that's useful to the OP or not is a different topic, perhaps the OP's hands *are* tied in some way. But it will influence their future decisions and benefits future readers.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, hopefully the OP will take it in the spirit it was intended.