# Disruptive answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, behavior

<sup>Disclamer: I know this was already discussed at least in two Q&As: *[Answering a question with a different approach altogether](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341391/answering-a-question-with-a-different-approach-altogether)* / *[Submit an Answer which does not offer a solution to the exact scenario but solves the problem nevertheless?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308949/submit-an-answer-which-does-not-offer-a-solution-to-the-exact-scenario-but-solve)*</sup>

<sup>Note: I've completely rephrased this question, because I think community got too focused on a concrete case that saddened me yesterday, but my intention was just looking for validation in the topic of this meta question itself...</sup>

Since I started to contribute on Stack Overflow, I've been actively answering issues where not always I've provided the *expected answer by the OP*. As I've already said, *not always*, but *sometimes* I tend to provide what I would call *disruptive answers* addressing issues using alternate approaches that based on my knowledge, I would find *a better one*.

From my standpoint, I feel happy with that way of answering to questions, because I would say that *quality answers* aren't the ones that may give an *instant solution* to the OP. Usually I feel that a good answer should be a one that addresses both the surface and background of the problem. In summary, I love solving the *root of the issue*.

I identify those answers as *disruptive ones* because you need to convince the OP that it's the way to go and once the OP realizes that's *his/her solution*, it might happen that they need a big refactor on their project code base. Isn't this positively annoying for the OP?

I've wanted to ask this question many times, basically because I've had to deal with other contributors pointing me that *I'm not answering the question*, and I've never arrived to any definitive conclusion whenever that recurrent discussion takes place. Hence I'm looking for the community advise.

**Are disruptive answers a bad habit? Or should I go on with them when I find that they can be useful for the OP and the community altogether?**

Comment: BTW I can rephrase my question in StackOverflow to make it more clear and useful for future visitors

Comment: By the community reception to my concern, I understand that next time I'll ask software design issues  They're likely to be considered XY problems, or maybe I'll need to post them on SoftwareEngineering.SE instead of StackOverflow...

Comment: I downvoted this meta question because I see no reason for there to ever have been an issue. You could have just posted your answer and not said anything, and there would never have been an issue. It is up to the community at large to decide the usefulness of an answer, not you alone.

Comment: @TinyGiant Absolutely, I posted this question here in Meta because I've been criticized many times because of answering something absolutely different from what the OP was asking for but I could demonstrate that you need to provide a solution which can show quality rather than just make happy the OP to get some reputation points...

Comment: "They're likely to be considered XY problems, or maybe I'll need to post them on SoftwareEngineering.SE instead of StackOverflow..." -- There is nothing deeply inappropriate about your question; you just phrased it in a slightly unclear way (by putting the failed attempt, rather than your actual problem, upfront) that led it to be taken as a XY question. I still don't see what the meta-issue is.

Comment: @duplode Ok ok, maybe I felt excessively concerned, it's also my personality... I tend to put on doubt myself about everything, it's my way of going beyond of me and learn from others :)

Comment: Here comes the meta effect... We can't have nice thing! Your question is good, ser's answer is good too.

Comment: @PierreLebon My answer was valid, because the problem was a wrong design reasoning, that's all :\ BTW, I've deleted it, and I've request to delete the Q&A, because I really feel that I would have a hard time to rephrase the question in a way that even Servy's answer could be useful. See that Servy's answer could be applied to any question that would involve trying to workaround C# generic type variance rules, which **wasn't** my intention from scratch. I believe we/I should miss this Q&A (continued in the next comment)

Comment: @PierreLebon I would frame this question more in the context of a forgetfulness of a C# generic type parameter constraint (which drove me to a completely wrong design). So I really hope that the Q&A will be deleted and also I hope that next time I could contribute an interesting question...

Comment: @PierreLebon About the meta effect :D Maybe you're talking about this Q&A, on which seems that no one wants to add their point about my concerns because my own question has a lot of downvotes? I really believe that it would be very important for the community that my concern could be solved based on many opinions so we could conclude what's the most accepted one by the community...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, A question with a valid answer will never be delete. But don't over think about it. Give it some time. Let Meta calm down. those down vote may came from ppl that was trying to be suportive with the biggest Rep

Comment: @PierreLebon This is sad, I'll take your advice to move forward myself... During today or tomorrow I'll try to rephrase again that Q&A so it can both reflect my mistaken design and what was the root problem. Thank you for your good words ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Frankly, I don't see what the meta-problem here is, nor why you had to have that argument with the other answerer, nor why you call your answer "disruptive". From what I can tell by skimming that Q&A, your question was formulated as a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "Y is impossible" is an acceptable answer for a XY problem, and so is "your real problem is X, here is how to do it". ("Y is impossible, but you can achieve X in this way" would be even better, but that's besides the point.)

---

Quoting an older revision of this question:

> I'm trying to understand if answers that completely differ from the attempted solution are fine in StackOverflow.

In general: *yes, they are*.

An exception to this general principle is when the asker restricts the scope of the answers in a sensible manner. For instance, if the question is "How do I achieve X with framework F? I tried using Y and it didn't quite do what I wanted" and F has a feature Z that is a perfectly reasonable way to achieve X, it is not a good idea to answer with "Switch to framework G and use its W feature". On the other hand, if the asker's choice of tools will lead them into a dead-end, it is entirely fine to suggest something completely different.

Comment: Well I was sure someone would address my concern based on the linked Q&A, BTW, I've had this problem in the past (I don't know which Q&As right now...), where always some user has stated "you don't answer the question" while the OP feels the opposite.

Comment: In my particular Q&A, probably may be a XY problem or maybe not. This is another concern. Why? Because I could drop the sample code and the attempted solution at all, and the question would be still complete: I want to do X and I don't find a way to get Y, and I didn't close the door to get another X and another Y. At the end of the day, it was an architectural/design problem where I din't care if I need to go for another X and Y.

Comment: Correction: I could drop the source code and the attempted solution, and rephrasing the question to just say "what would be a solution to this *impossible X*", right? Probably someone could comment out *what have you tried so far?*... And I could add to my question that I was in the wrong way trying an absolutely crazy solution.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer it is very common for (self-)answer to provide answer for the problem that is different from what is actually written in the corresponding question. Amount of context that is usually missing from the question is rarely understood by the questioner - they assume everyone knows they tools, source code, last 3 days of debugging, business constraints and the like. This results in other people reading question totally differently and thus causing conflict... Not really sure what can be done short of OP to provide more context.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer "Please don't focus on the concrete Q&A" -- The answer to your broader question is a clear and loud "yes", except in some cases in which the asker restricts the scope of the answers in a sensible way. That seems uncontroversial enough to not require further comment. A XY question can be seen as a case of an asker slipping in an unnecessary (and therefore not sensible) restriction and, as a consequence, asking the "wrong" question.

Comment: @duplode I would still add the *loud yes*, because I've been having troubles many times with users which criticize some (not all) of my answers even when the community and the OP have found upvoting them or even commenting out that it was a nice catch.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It would be useful that you could add an answer with this reasoning instead of leaving a comment :D

Comment: Hi, @duplode. I've rephrased my question and I've removed the link to the Q&A that motivated me to finally look for the community advise. Basically, I've experienced this problem many times (yesterday it was the first time that happened with an own question anyway...), and I was/I'm looking for community advise to be sure I'm not mistaken when I provide completely different approaches than what the OP (or even some contributors) might expect.

Comment: @duplode So,... I would really love that you could also rephrase your answer in a way that it could represent an advise not only for me, but a conclusion about the topic so it can be referenced by me and even others when this situation happens again. Please note that my concern isn't about on how to ask questions or if the yesterday's question was an XY problem. My concern is completely focused on an approach to answer questions.Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Okay; I have appended a modified version of my comment to the answer.

Comment: @duplode Thank you very much :) Yeah, you're right that we shouldn't answer a question suggesting "switch from framework A to B", because most of the times this is 100% subjective or it can objectively impossible to give a good advise if you don't know the project and its actual requirements, timing, ...

Comment: @duplode For example, today [I've answered a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412507/repositories-design-confusion/42417762#42417762) about *repository pattern* that can be a good example of my approach. The OP wanted advise about his approach and I provided an alternative that changes his point of view, but I did because I really think that there's a design flaw on OP's reasoning.

Comment: @duplode That answer isn't the most extreme example of what I call a *disrputive answer* but more or less it shows what I wanted to ask here at Meta. Think that during these 6 years at StackOverflow I've been receiving complaints from some users in terms of "hey you don't answer the question, the OP didn't request this" and my point is that if I would have to solve an issue in their office I would have had arranged a meeting to try to convince the OP about changing their mind and going forward with a better solution.

Comment: @duplode Yesterday I got troubles in that messed Q&A and I got very concerned, because I try to be self-critical with myself, I always believe that even when I feel very convinced about my approach there's room to be mistaken so I thought that Meta would be a good place to be sure I'm in the right track...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The way I see it, many if not most meta-disputes are ultimately about different expectations of how literally the site rules and/or Q&As should be interpreted. As a moderate contextualist, I find your approach to be generally fine, but I don't expect ever seeing a true consensus on the broader underlying issue. (By the way, by "literal" I don't mean only the knee-jerk "You didn't give the OP what they wanted; you aren't helping!", but also the more refined "The OP is too confused; this question isn't useful and you shouldn't have bothered answering in the first place".)

Comment: @duplode You're right. Usefulness is a very subjective concept. Anyway this Q&A can remain open to host other opinions that can be voted/upvoted, so the positive vote ranking can demonstrate what's the subjective but overall opinion about this topic so it can be considered the *de facto* summary of what the community says about the whole answering approach...

Comment: @duplode At the end of the day, for me the key point is that we should be more respectful. Stack Overflow is contributed by people from many different countries and cultures, and many different ages too. That means we can't close our mind to what we consider a *bad answer*. There's no universal concensus on what should be the archetype of a *good answer* but there're some insights that can be objectively valued, and that's why Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @duplode So.. maybe strong assertions like "this doesn't answer the question" should be made carefully, because not everyone has the same knowledge and background, and what can be *too broad* or any other consideration for another user can be absolutely clear and it can be answered, even with an answer that was not expected by the OP!

Comment: @duplode Well, thank you for this enjoyable discussion and I hope I might be less concerned when I get criticism about my answers. I feel good about myself because whenever I realized my answer wasn't fine with the OP expectations, I've had no problem in deleting it even if I've already had upvotes. I don't care about reputation points but about useful contributions, and the most important thing I care is improving myself everyday: fixing issues you know new use cases that you might need to face tomorrow and this is very very useful.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer [1/2] That I wrote "useful" in my previous comment kind of betrays my own contextualism :) A hard-line literalist would probably have used "too broad/unclear/primarily opinion-based" instead, to reflect the standard close reasons, under the assumption that they can be applied objectively to every question without any flexibility of interpretation. -- an assumption which is, in my view flawed.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer [2/2] That said, I do think there is a reasonable interpretation for e.g. the current set of closing reasons, and that, all in all, most closures are reasonable (even though some of them seem to be more misused than others, "too broad" in particular). I just don't believe in immediately disregarding questions due to some "red flag" phrase, or that "shoot first, ask questions later" is a good way of dealing with *every* question.