# What should I do with answers that don't directly answer the OP?

Tags: discussion, answers

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825774/confusion-about-setting-a-optional-variable) and [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143259/failed-to-compare-images-one-from-a-uibutton).

Some answers are good and can solve the problem, but isn't directly addressing the OP's question. For example:

- Q: "Why isn't my code producing the intended results?" A: "Instead of your approach, try this"
- Q: "Why do I get this error?" A: "I don't know the cause of the error, but try this code instead"

And so on. Even though they "work" and are accepted and upvoted, they don't really answer the OP. In the first link I provided, the answerer doesn't directly answer the question. What should I do? Should I flag as NAA or downvote or...?

Comment: I probably wouldn’t flag them as NAA… often I’ll just leave comments. Keep in mind that partial answers are not discouraged, so something like _“**I don't know the cause of the error**, but try this code instead”_. would be fine, as long as the “try this” part isn’t a mere guess with no explanation of why someone should try it or how it works or solves the problem.

Comment: @Xufox But eventually, the accepted answer should address the OP's question?

Comment: Ideally, yes, of course. You’re right, such answers being _accepted_ is a bigger problem…

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here. Your first example is not accepted nor upvoted. The second example was accepted *by you*, so I fail to see the problem in the answer. If the OP's way of thinking is wrong, why would the correct answer follow that line of thinking? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I usually intentionally avoid to answer the direct question and I provide a complete new way to achieve things when I think the OP is overcomplicating a simple thing that can be done easily ... so for me such answer are legit and could be accepted as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: Closely related: [*Disruptive answers*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344350/2751851)

Comment: "But eventually, the accepted answer should address the OP's question?"  Not necessarily.  If someone asks how to shoot themselves in the foot, oftentimes it's *preferable* that they *don't* get an answer, and that they are only ever given *safe* solutions to whatever underlying problem they have.  In some situations providing an answer to the literal question asked is *actively harmful*, and should be voted on accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally considered that "attempting to solve the underlying problem that resulted in the user asking the question" is an attempted answer to the question.  It's not "not an answer".

If you feel that it's not a useful answer, and you think that answering the literal question asked would be better (or that they improperly diagnosed the underlying problem, or provided a poor solution to said underlying problem), you're free to vote accordingly.